# How to access Titanium.Network.HttpClient.responseData cache on android 4.2.2

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to write a sort of download manager app for nexus 7 with android 4.2.2 using Titanium SDK v3.1.1.GA. All works well except that I am not able to resume a download from an aborted connection.

Lets say I have downloaded 546 bytes of a 1024 bytes file and then the connection was aborted. So next time I connect I want to start the download from 547 bytes - 1024 bytes. But I have no way to realize that 546 bytes have already been downloaded.

Because:

1. These 546 bytes are stored in app cache dir (/sdcard/Android/data/com.packagename/cache/_tmp/tihttp-XXXXXXXXXXXtmp) to which I have no access and the docs say not to rely upon these files.
2. I also tried write to the destination file incrementally in the ondatastream callback. But problem is data gets accumulated in HTTPClient.responseData over the life of the connection and I cannot remove the already read data from it as it is a read only property.

So the only option left for me is to write to the file in onload callback. But in case of an abort onload callback is not called and I lose all the data that has been cached and that was available in HTTPClient.responseData.

Comment: I will try copying the responseData in the onerror callback and post the results.

Comment: No luck with the onerror callback. responseData goes undefined on an aborted connection.